# Combine - Subscriber gets cancelled silently when subscribing a second time

Tags: swift, combine, delegation, viper-architecture

I am trying to replace delegation pattern with Combine.

The architecture of my app is a VIPER, so I need to pass the sink subscriber from one module to another. The use case is i have data from module A (list) that needs to be show to module B (detail view), and module B can also update the data so I need to get it back to module A also.

With delegates it works okay but when I use a sink subscriber I am facing an issue.

The first time I go from module A to module B, I pass the subscriber and then subscribe it to the publisher (from moduleB) it works well and the subscriber in module A receives all the events from module B.

But then when dismissing the module B and routing again from A to B, then the subscriber receives immediately a cancel event when trying to subscribe again: **receive subscription: (PublishedSubject) ... receive cancel ...**

I made a very simplified example to show what is happening:

**Module A:**

```
class ViewController_A: UIViewController {
    
    var subscriber: AnySubscriber<String, Never>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createSubscriber()
    }
    
    func createSubscriber() {
        let subscriber = Subscribers.Sink<String, Never>(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print(completion)
            }, receiveValue: { value in
                print(value)
            })
        self.subscriber = AnySubscriber(subscriber)
    }
    
    func showViewControllerB() {
        let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB()
        viewControllerB.passSubscriber(AnySubscriber(subscriber))
    }
}
```

**Module B:**

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var publisher: Published<String>.Publisher { get }
    func passSubscriber(_ subscriber: AnySubscriber<String, Never>)
}

class ViewController_B: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    
    @Published var word: String = "House"
    var publisher: Published<String>.Publisher { $word }
    
    func passSubscriber(_ subscriber: AnySubscriber<String, Never>) {
        publisher
            .print()
            .subscribe(subscriber)
    }
    
    func dismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**When routing..**

```
let viewControllerA = ViewController_A()
viewControllerA.showViewController_B() // When presenting B for the first time, receiving events here
// Dismiss B here...
viewControllerA.showViewControllerB() // When presenting B again (hence subscribing again), the subscription gets cancelled here without receiving any events/values
```

I noticed something interesting.. When I create the subscriber again every time I route to module B instead of creating it only one time in `viewDidLoad`, it seems to work okay, but I am not sure why.

Does this mean that a subscriber cannot subscribe to another publisher once it subscribed to one, even when the previous publisher doesn't exist anymore?

How I can make it work in my delegation case?

Comment: Is there more you are not showing us? Your showViewControllerB creates a view controller and then destroys it instantly.

Comment: By the way I think your analysis is quite right. You only create the subscriber once, in viewDidLoad, and a subscriber cannot be reused. You just need to create the subscriber afresh each time A generates B.

Comment: Thnks for your reply! Yes sorry it was just a test project to show what was happening, but the reals project is made on Viper and the module doesnt get destroyed instantly.

Comment: Oh I see so there is no way to unsuscribe a subscriber in order to subscribe to a new publiser?

Comment: There is no _need_ to. These are lightweight objects. You are making a pipeline of communication between two _real_ objects, the view controllers. When the communication ends because one of those objects is gone, the pipeline is over. Now you have a new ViewControllerB, make a new pipeline.

Comment: Still, what is the reason for subscriber to receive `cancel`? In the project I experience the same problem, but I am unable to reproduce it in the playground: subscriber can be subscribed to any number of publishers and deallocation of one of them prior to or after second subscription does not produce a cancel event in the playground. Is there something different happening in the project? What exactly is the reason for `cancel` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create the subscriber again everytime I route to module B instead of creating it only one time in viewdidload, it seems to work okay

Correct, because that's just what you're supposed to do.

A subscriber that has been subscribed and then cancelled / completed is *over*, just as a publisher that has been subscribed to and then cancelled / completed is *over*. These are lightweight objects, created in order to facilitate communication between two "real" endpoints. When one of the endpoints comes to an end, the communication comes to an end.

So if you need a new pipeline of communication, you just make a new publisher / subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thats very interesting. What i don't understand is, I never cancel or complete the subscriber, so why does it get cancel right away when i subscribe to it again with a new publiser?

Comment: My impression is that what you're seeing is the _first_ pipeline cancelling because you are trying to subscribe its subscriber to another pipeline. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you @matt. even if i could not find any documentation related to that issue, I will accept your answer! I will just try to recreate it anyway to be sure it will not be cancelled. thanks!!